# iframe on div container not working as expected on IE8/firefox45.9

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a page navigation as portable as possible. I'm using Chrome 58 and the page is displayed as expected: the iframe is resized according to the td container, but is not working in IE and firefox which displays the iframe in the middle of the cell. Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="language" content="ES">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="css.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="js.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
        <title>Mi sitio</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="navUI">
            <tr>
                <td id="navHeader" colspan="2">Tema general</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="MenuHeader">Men&uacute;</td>
                <td rowspan="4"><iframe src="intro.htm" id="navField"></iframe></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="MenuItems" onclick="navPage('page1'); return false;">Item 1</td>     
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="MenuItems" onclick="navPage('page2'); return false;">Item 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="spander">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";

html, body, table {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

body {
    font:12px Verdana, Arial, Sans-serif;
}

table#navUI, td {
    border:1px solid black;
}

td#navHeader {
    text-align:center;
    height:30px;
}

td#MenuHeader {
    width:10%;
    text-align:center;
}

td.MenuItems {
    width:10%;
}

td.MenuItems:hover {
    background-color:#BDBEE1;
    cursor:pointer;
}

td.spander {
    width:10%;
    height:100%;
}

#navField {
    border:none;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

The idea is to keep pure html and css without jquery. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the `td` which contains the `iframe`:

```
vertical-align:top;height:100%;
```

Here's a fiddle which works in Firefox:

https://jsfiddle.net/3urm8kx8/1/